# How to use greek letters in pgf-umlsd (or generally terms starting with \)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm drawing a sequence diagram with [pgf-umlsd](https://code.google.com/p/pgf-umlsd/) and I want to incorporate a greek letter in a message description. 
Something like `\mess[1]{a}{Message $\alpha$}{b}`.
While *pgf-umlsd* seems to allow `$` for using the math mode, it apparently does not allow any `\` (so I can't write e.g. `\alpha`).

`\protect` also doesn't work. Furthermore, I've defined a variable with `\def\alph{$\alpha$}`, and used it with `\mess[1]{a}{Message \alph}{b}`, but also to no avail.
If the definition is set to `\def\alph{$alpha$}`, it works fine but of course doesn't produce an alpha. So, `\` is apparently not generally prohibited inside *pgf-umlsd* message descritiptions.

Is there a possibility to somehow use greek letters?

Here is a minimal example of the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}                                                                                     
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}                                                                                      
\begin{document}                                                                                            
\begin{figure} [ht!]                                                                                        
\def\alph{$\alpha$}                                                                                         
\def\bet {$beta$}                                                                                           
\begin{sequencediagram}                                                                                     
    \newthread{a}{Alice}{Alice}                                                                             
    \newthread{b}{Bob}{Bob}                                                                                 
    \mess[1]{a}{Message \alph}{b} %This doesn't compile                                                     
    \mess[1]{a}{Message \bet} {b} %This compiles but generates no greek letter                              
\end{sequencediagram}                                                                                       
\end{figure}                                                                                                
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you create a minimal (non-)working example? Just something like `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}\begin{document}<add code for a single small diagram with such a message>\end{document}`.

Comment: Your minimal example seems to be broken, \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows} needs to be added.

Comment: @Twig Worked fine here ... `pgf-umlsd` loads those things.

Comment: Ah ok, i just used which ever one was currently installed, probably from texlive 2013.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is caused by how `\mess` is defined (from v0.7 of `pgf-umlsd.sty`):

```
\newcommand{\mess}[4][0]{
  \stepcounter{seqlevel}
  \path
  (#2)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (mess from) {};
  \addtocounter{seqlevel}{#1}
  \path
  (#4)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (mess to) {};
  \draw[->,>=angle 60] (mess from) -- (mess to) node[midway, above]
  {#3};

  \node (#3 from) at (mess from) {};
  \node (#3 to) at (mess to) {};
}
```

The third argument (denoted by `#3`) is the message, but it is also used to define two additional nodes, at the start and end of the arrow, as you can see in the two last lines,

```
\node (#3 from) at (mess from) {};
\node (#3 to) at (mess to) {};
```

I don't know exactly what the limitations are, but having `$\alpha$` in a node name doesn't work at least.

Now, if those node names aren't used anywhere, you could just eliminate those nodes, by redefining the command with

```
\renewcommand{\mess}[4][0]{
  \stepcounter{seqlevel}
  \path
  (#2)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (mess from) {};
  \addtocounter{seqlevel}{#1}
  \path
  (#4)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (mess to) {};
  \draw[->,>=angle 60] (mess from) -- (mess to) node[midway, above]
  {#3};    
}
```

but if they are needed, other things won't work, so this may or may not be helpful.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}                                                                                     
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}                                                                                      

\begin{document}                                                                                            
\begin{sequencediagram}                                                                                     
    \newthread{a}{Alice}{Alice}                                                                             
    \newthread{b}{Bob}{Bob}                                                                                 
    \mess[1]{a}{Message alfa}{b} 
    \mess[1]{a}{Message beta} {b}

% draw borders around the above mentioned nodes:
\draw [ultra thick,red] (Message beta from.south east) rectangle (Message beta from.north west);
\draw [ultra thick,green] (Message beta to.south east) rectangle (Message beta to.north west);
\end{sequencediagram}                                                                                       

% redefine the \mess
\renewcommand{\mess}[4][0]{
  \stepcounter{seqlevel}
  \path
  (#2)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (mess from) {};
  \addtocounter{seqlevel}{#1}
  \path
  (#4)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (mess to) {};
  \draw[->,>=angle 60] (mess from) -- (mess to) node[midway, above]
  {#3};
}

\begin{sequencediagram}                                                                                     
    \newthread{a}{Alice}{Alice}                                                                             
    \newthread{b}{Bob}{Bob}                                                                                 
    \mess[1]{a}{Message $\alpha$}{b} 
    \mess[1]{a}{Message $\beta$} {b} 

\end{sequencediagram}                                                                                       
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I suggest two ways for solving your issue.

1. Redefine `\mess` to “stringify” the problematic argument in the proper place
2. Define a `\Mess` command with an additional optional argument (a string that refers to the text); if the second mandatory argument to `\Mess` (corresponding to the same place in `\mess`) is characters only, you don't need to add the label in the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

%%%% First way: redefine \mess
\renewcommand{\mess}[4][0]{
  \stepcounter{seqlevel}
  \path
  (#2)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (mess from) {};
  \addtocounter{seqlevel}{#1}
  \path
  (#4)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (mess to) {};
  \draw[->,>=angle 60] (mess from) -- (mess to) node[midway, above]
  {#3};

  \node (\detokenize{#3} from) at (mess from) {};
  \node (\detokenize{#3} to) at (mess to) {};
}

%%%% Second way: define a command with a different syntax

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Mess}{O{0}mmom}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#4}
    {\xmess{#1}{#2}{#3}{#3}{#5}}
    {\xmess{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\xmess}{mmmmm}{
  \stepcounter{seqlevel}
  \path
  (#2)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (mess from) {};
  \addtocounter{seqlevel}{#1}
  \path
  (#5)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (mess to) {};
  \draw[->,>=angle 60] (mess from) -- (mess to) node[midway, above]
  {#3};

  \node (#4 from) at (mess from) {};
  \node (#4 to) at (mess to) {};
}


\begin{document}

\begin{sequencediagram}
\newthread{a}{Alice}{Alice}
\newthread{b}{Bob}{Bob}
\mess[1]{a}{Message $\alpha$}{b}
\mess[1]{a}{Message $\beta$} {b}
\end{sequencediagram}

\begin{sequencediagram}
\newthread{a}{Alice}{Alice}
\newthread{b}{Bob}{Bob}
\Mess[1]{a}{Message $\alpha$}[malpha]{b}
\Mess[1]{a}{Message $\beta$}[mbeta] {b}
\end{sequencediagram}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but here is something similar to your example that works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure} [ht!]
        \newcommand{\alphn}{$\alpha$}
        \newcommand{\bet}{$\beta$}
        \begin{sequencediagram}
            \newthread{a}{Alice}
            \newthread{b}{Bob}
            \mess{a}{Message \alphn}{b} %This doesn't compile
            \mess{a}{Message \bet } {b} %This compiles but generates no greek letter
        \end{sequencediagram}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Image produced by code]

I think in general you should avoid raw TeX commands such as `\def`, and use the LaTeX equivilent of `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand`. I didn't have any problems with greek letters, but the way you used pdf-umlsd differed some what from the example code here:
http://www.csrdu.org/nauman/2011/11/24/creating-uml-sequence-diagrams-with-tikz-in-latex/
, so that's probably where the error was.

Comment: Also `\alph` is already defined, so i changed it to `\alphn`. `\alph{counter}` prints the counter as a lowercase letter, a,b,c...

Comment: I get a `Missing \endcsname inserted` error with your code. TeX Live 2013, recently updated.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get any errors, so can't fix this one.

Comment: ah, I seem to be using v0.5 from 2009/09/30

Comment: I get the error now with v0.7